# Duplicate Application Icons appear in Dash

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, unity-dash

I have duplicate application icons appearing in Dash with no idea how to resolve.

[image: dupicons]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well it came down to a simple capital letter to confuse Dash.

`/usr/share/applications/docky.desktop`

`~/.local/share/applications/Docky.desktop`

Removing the latter desktop entry solved the issue.